# How to make UIButton overhang over parent view and still make it all selectable?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIButton which is a child of a custom UIView. I've placed the button so its center is directly on top of the top right pixel of its parent view. Currently only 25% of the button (the area of the button which is within the the parent's view bound) is selectable. Is there a way of making the rest of the 75% selectable?

[Here's a link to a diagram of the problem](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/580/overhangingbutton.jpg/)

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how you have your app setup, but you could try myView.clipsToBounds = NO;

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't help. When myView.clipsToBounds = YES then it clips the unselectable bit of the button, which is what i expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your button is a subview of the bigger parent view, touch events are not registered outside the bounds of the parent view.

I recommend that you add the button as a subview to the same view that the bigger view is in. You will have to convert the frame location to keep it positioned the same way.

UPDATE

You can convert coordinates automatically using the UIView convertRect:toView: method.

Comment: Thanks, this will do for now.